# 3D array of pointers with dynamic and fixed sizes - 1st dimension type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic array that contains another dynamic array within it's rows. Every row array contains values of a fixed size arrays of pointers of length 2.

So I've ended with below type declaration:

```
double *(**arrayName)[2];
```

Such definition clearly works for second and third nesting level. As an example:

```
arrayName[3] = new double*[4][2];

double x { 5 };
arrayName[3][2][1] = &x;
```

What I'm struggling with is 1st dimension declaration. I'm trying with something like below, but no luck:

```
arrayName = new double**[12][2];
```

I'm thinking that some parenthesis can help with above.
With what type shuch initialization should be done?

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use `std::vector`  which should be the go to for most dynamic arrays.

Comment: Fyi, I'm not entirely convinced your declaration is accurate to what you want. Per cdecl.org, your decl is: "declare arrayName as pointer to pointer to array 2 of pointer to double" . If that's accurate, then your self-posted description *is not*. Your verbiage: "contains values of a fixed size arrays of length 2" should be "contains values of a fixed size arrays *of pointers* of length 2"

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the link, will be useful. Yes, generated description is accurate, that is what I want to achieve.

@ drescherjm Correct. The goal or a difficulty is to use plain arrays.

Comment: use typedefs and/or classes and your life will be far easier.